# Transient simulation in Cadance

Tags: simulation, transient

I have been trying to do a transient simulation of a Power supply independent biasing circuit in Cadance but how much ever I try I do not see the transition of the states. I always get only the steady state even if I put the stop time in nano seconds ! This is the circuit that I am trying to simulate and I have marked the nets(Voltage) that I trying to view in my transient simulation,[image: Circuit diagram in Cadance]

The simulation result looks like this(below) and the time axis is in nanoseconds range but still I do not get to see a slope or anything other than the steady state response [image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdjty.jpg)

Could there be any reason why I am not able to see the transition ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transient simulation simulates the circuit's conditions over time. You seem to have **no component in your circuit which introduces a time varying voltage**.

Use a vpulse source instead of the vdc (V17), fill in it's properties so that it will step the supply voltage. Simulate that, **then check that the supply voltage has the transient step that you want to simulate**. If that is OK, look at the voltages inside the circuit.